# In Wonder Woman : Spirit of truth, why were people scared of her?

Tags: dc, comics, wonder-woman

Wonder Woman saves a girl from being crushed by a tank, but she gets scared of her instead, and a lot of people in middle east saw her as a threat.

Why were people not appreciating her before, but later they did ?

Comment: Because someone who can toss around tanks is a psychotic episode away from declaring themselves ruler of Earth?

Comment: Also, a lot of people in the Middle East aren't so keen on the idea of strong female role models.

Comment: Especially when wearing a costume inspired by the American flag. Apologies if she is in the costume from B vs. S

Comment: Isn't this the story arc for almost *every* super hero? They're almost universally depicted as terrifying the people they're trying to save/protect initially, regardless of the gender of the hero or the nationality of the victims.

Comment: Just by skimming over some reference material I would say because plot demands it.  The whole point of the plot was to show that you cant be above everyone and expect them to accept you as equal. You need to go down and be among the people. That's what Superman suggested to her. And when she goes back posing as Muslim women and than saves them from some bad guys they accept her. Also story is trying to show that even Superheros are humans (metaphorically speaking) and they have same issues as everyone else not some Gods who are above everyone.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Golden Age of Comic Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Comic_Books) both the heroes, and people's reactions to them, were unrealistic. If you watch some of the classic Superman cartoons from that time, Superman was not only altruistic, but mostly unquestioned. After all, he stopped the bad guys and that was all that mattered. Who cares that a man who can bend steel with his bare hands or incinerate them on a whim might be a threat?

This was where people like Stan Lee stepped in in the 1960s with some more realism. In the Marvel universe, superheroes weren't universally accepted. Spider Man, for instance, [was met with skepticism and/or fear](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_1)

> Thinking that Spider-Man has at last proved himself, Peter Parker is shocked when he reads J. Jonah Jameson's editorial in the next edition of the Daily Bugle. Spider-Man is accused of deliberately sabotaging the space capsule and staging the rescue as a publicity stunt. With public opinion turning against Spider-Man with each new editorial in the Daily Bugle, Peter Parker's position is as hopeless as ever.

The funny thing here is that **fear is a perfectly natural reaction to this**. We fear what we don't understand and a woman picking up a tank defies explanation. It would be far more unnatural if they had no fear at all. Instead, you have to prove yourself over time. A superhero with a track record is going to be more accepted than one with none at all.